# Why does .className = .... , doesnt work but classList.add() does?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .youtube-text {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: larger;
      }
      .subscribe-button {
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold';
        font-size: large;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-top: 12px ;
        padding-bottom: 12px ;
        padding-right: 12px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
      .is-subscribed {
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold';
        font-size: large;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-top: 12px ;
        padding-bottom: 12px ;
        padding-right: 12px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>

    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p2>Youtube Subscribe Button</p2><br><Br>
    <button class = 'subscribe-button' onclick="
      subscribeButton();
      ">Subscribe</button>
    <script async>
      function subscribeButton() {
        const subButton = document.querySelector('.subscribe-button');
        if (subButton.innerHTML === 'Subscribe'){
          subButton.innerHTML = 'Subscribed';
          subButton.classList.add('is-subscribed');
        }
        else {
          subButton.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
          subButton.classList.remove('is-subscribed');
        } 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .youtube-text {
        font-family: Arial;
        font-size: larger;
      }
      .subscribe-button {
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold';
        font-size: large;
        color: white;
        background-color: black;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-top: 12px ;
        padding-bottom: 12px ;
        padding-right: 12px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
      .is-subscribed {
        font-family: 'Arial Narrow Bold';
        font-size: large;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-top: 12px ;
        padding-bottom: 12px ;
        padding-right: 12px;
        border-radius: 20px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>

    </title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p2>Youtube Subscribe Button</p2><br><Br>
    <button class = 'subscribe-button' onclick="
      subscribeButton();
      ">Subscribe</button>
    <script async>
      function subscribeButton() {
        const subButton = document.querySelector('.subscribe-button');
        if (subButton.innerHTML === 'Subscribe'){
          subButton.innerHTML = 'Subscribed';
          subButton.className = 'is-subscribed';
        }
        else {
          subButton.innerHTML = 'Subscribe';
          subButton.className = 'subscribe-button';
        } 
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hello,
I am just starting in JS and was wondering about this problem I had .The code on top is the one that works and the one on the bottom is which doesn't , on first click it does change the class to is-subscribed but when I press the button it gives an error and doesn't change it anymore, I am just wondering why is that .

Comment: `classList.add` doesn't remove the existing class on that button (`subscribe-button` one), yet assignment to className does exactly that. That's why it breaks that querySelector (which is easy to see - just put a debugger on that `const subButton = ` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I press the button it gives an error and doesn't change it anymore

When you press the button, the code looks for an element by class:

```
const subButton = document.querySelector('.subscribe-button');
```

But there is no such element with that class.  You *removed* that class when you set the `className`:

```
subButton.className = 'is-subscribed';
```

This *replaced* the entire `class` with `is-subscribed`, rather than *add* it to the list of classes.

So presumably the error you get happens here:

```
if (subButton.innerHTML === 'Subscribe'){
```

And says something along the lines of "cannot read properties of `null`" when trying to read `innerHTML`.